# TreeMap alternative in Java

Tags: java

I have an existing Map implementation which sorts the keys in natural order since it is being converted to Tree Map

```
  1. Map <CustomInterfaceObject, Double> hashMap = service.getHashMap();
  2. Map <CustomInterfaceObject, Double> treeMap = new TreeMap<CustomInterfaceObject,Double>(hashMap)
```

The Tree map has unfortunately become a pain now since I am getting a class cast exception due to an additional implementation of the CustomInterfaceObject. I would appreciate if an alternative exists for line 2 in my code. Using a LinkedHashMap in line 2 is failing my existing test cases

Comment: Please show the exact exception and the code that causes that exception.

Comment: When I do a treeMap.get(CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject), I get a ClassCastException

Comment: Does `CustomInterfaceImplementationObject` implement `CustomInterfaceObject`?

Comment: yes it does implement it

Comment: Java `Map` takes two generic parameters. In your code there's only one parameter. Please edit the post to provide a correct code.

Comment: That is not the exact exception (preferably including the stacktrace)

Comment: I guess the problem is in the implementation of your `compareTo` method. Nevertheless post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Stacktrace: java.lang.ClassCastException..at java.lang.Enum.compareTo(Enum.java:149)

Comment: Under a rush situation I had to post it. I am disappointed with all the down votes!

Comment: I am not here to argue but not sure why the 'on hold' on this question? Infact the answer by 'Jesper' was of immense help to me and fixed a problem which was making me loose my sleep on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html): either the type that you use for the keys must implement interface [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or you use the constructor of `TreeMap` that takes a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and you'll have to pass it an implementation of `Comparator` that can compare the keys.

This is necessary because `TreeMap` needs to know how to compare the keys so that it can sort the entries in the map by key.

You get a `ClassCastException` because the `CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject` that you are using does not implement `Comparable`, and you are also not using the constructor of `TreeMap` that takes a `Comparator`.

**First possible solution** - make `CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject` implement `Comparable<CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject>`:

```
public class CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject
    implements CustomInterfaceObject, Comparable<CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject other) {
        // implement this as necessary, compare this and other
    }
}
```

**Second possible solution** - pass a `Comparator<CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject>` to the constructor of `TreeMap`:

```
Comparator<CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject> comparator =
    new Comparator<>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject o1,
                           CustomInterfaceImplemenationObject o2) {
            // implement as necessary, compare o1 and o2
        }
    };

Map<CustomInterfaceObject, Double> treeMap =
        new TreeMap<CustomInterfaceObject,Double>(comparator);
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
```

Comment: The second solution worked perfectly in my situation. Thanks